# won't pass the terminal on linux 12.10 on a I Mac g5

Tags: system-installation

I made a video of booting up with Ubuntu 12.10 installed i can't pass the terminal.need your help please

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BziP1rXyFg4&feature=c4-overview&list=UUC6ZYeSSbjvOmHwM0WycHiw

Answer (score 0):

Try typing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>. If that doesn't work try typing "startx" into the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing problems with starting `lightdm` then you can start that with

```
sudo start lightdm
```

For more information: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM